# Html generate data and print from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

In the below code,

in a.html there is this code as,

```
         <div id="tableview"></div>//Data loaded dynamically

         <input type="button" id="printbtn" onclick="print()"/>             
         <script>
         function print()
         {
            var data=$('#tableview').html();
            dataobj.print();
          }
```

In b.html

I need to print a.html without opening it ,But without opening it how will the data in the div get generated and how to print only this data from b.html

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Update: This answer is assuming that no postback should occur based on your question. (No Ajax)

If you only have one print view per a page you can apply a media=print filter on to the page.  Load both views initially and only show the screen view to the screen.

```
<Style href="print.css" media="print" />
```

You can set all the screen display to hidden and show the prinatble view:

```
 * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  #tableview * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

Comment: IMO, this is the right way to do it. There is no reason to fetch the page again; this is precisely what print stylesheets are for!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an Ajax call to b.htm
2. Get the content of the div you want.
3. Return the data into a hidden div in a.htm
4. Make a print style sheet which everything is hidden in that view and only the previously hidden div is visible.
5. call your print function

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make an ajax request to b.html to get the content and then print it.

```
function contentprint()
{
$.ajax({
           url : "b.html",
           success : function (data) {
           var data1=data;
           data1.print();
}
});
}
```

HTH

Comment: yes that is correct.

just the url bit should be "b.htm#mycontent"